MissingServletRequestParameterException on @RequestParam for form-data after upgrade to Spring 6
I recently upgraded an app to Spring 6/Tomcat 10 (from Spring 5 & Tomcat 9) and some code stopped working. I've got some JS code that sends a jQuery ajax request (content-type being form-data) like this:
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('fname', 'testfile.jpg');
fd.append('data', blob);
fd.append('id', 2);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
     url: '/my-endpoint',
     data: fd,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function (data) {...},
     error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {...}
});

And my Spring endpoint:
@RequestMapping(value = "/my-endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public MyResponse addFeaturedAsset(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam("id") long id) { 
    ...
}

Before the upgrade, I could receive the id param just fine.
After the upgrade, the endpoint is not hit and I get this error instead:
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'id' for method parameter type long is not present

If I inspect the HTTP request, I see
content-type:
multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryN31XRU7ftyhAFwb0

and payload is
fname: testfile.jpg
data: /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gHYSU....
id: 2

Before the upgrade, we had this bean defined:
@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
  CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
  return resolver;
}

But Spring 6 has dropped CommonsMultipartResolver and we had to remove that bean as part of the migration. I have a feeling this might be the cause of the problem.
Does anyone know how to make the ajax request work with Spring 6? I haven't found any migration guides for CommonsMultipartResolver.
Thanks!

hello isn't really a long value. For more info enable debug logging (or even trace) and see what is happening on the Spring side of things.

@M.Deinum sorry, that was bad copy-paste. I've updated the question. Thanks for pointing it out.
